# How to get new signature when call restserver.php of facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, signature

I have issue about generate sign for request restserver of facebook.

It's my request:

```
https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?api_key=882a8490361da98702bf97a021ddc14d&credentials_type=password&email=xxxxx&format=JSON&generate_machine_id=1&generate_session_cookies=1&locale=vi_VN&method=auth.login&password=xxxxx&return_ssl_resources=0&v=1.0&sig=2ca6b594f82672d9dfdf14f7b80e2af0
```

And facebook response

```
{"error_code":104,"error_msg":"Incorrect signature (104)","request_args":[{"key":"api_key","value":"882a8490361da98702bf97a021ddc14d"},{"key":"credentials_type","value":"password"},{"key":"email","value":"xxxxx"},{"key":"format","value":"JSON"},{"key":"generate_machine_id","value":"1"},{"key":"generate_session_cookies","value":"1"},{"key":"locale","value":"vi_VN"},{"key":"method","value":"auth.login"},{"key":"password","value":"--sanitized--"},{"key":"return_ssl_resources","value":"0"},{"key":"v","value":"1.0"},{"key":"sig","value":"2ca6b594f82672d9dfdf14f7b80e2af0"}],"error_subcode":0}
```

I was met error code of facebook is `104 : Incorrect signature (104)`, so can anyone help me to share how can I re-generate sign for new request with another user?

thank you so much.

Comment: What is this supposed to do? All these old REST endpoints are deprecated AFAIK, you should really use the current API if at all possible.

Comment: There's some spam and other attacks that still use some of the old endpoints, i think

Comment: Where did you get the sig you have in your example?

Comment: I found and was use endpoint [getSign.php?u=xxxxx&p=xxxxx](https://tool.puno2.com/getSign.php?u=xxxxx&p=xxxxx) to get sign but I don't know at the backend of this endpoint the account will be saved to them system or not, and I want to know how to get sign like this endpoint. thanks

Comment: @misorude Now I want to get access_token from facebook api to, but I want using API to get it not using popup login or click login on web page, it's problem i was met right now. can you help me, thanks

Comment: @Igy Can you clearly about this for me, because, currently some application still used old endpoint of facebook to request api?

Comment: You have absolutely no business getting an access token without the proper user interaction. You need a user or page access token - then use the login dialog, as intended.

Comment: I don't know what code you're using as an example, but as WizKid said, that endpoint is very old and not at all related to the currently documented and supported SDKs or APIs. Start at the current developer site, and look at examples that are at least newer than 2013 or so, but preferably using the current API versions

Comment: thank you all, I was found solution for my cases.